# autocomplete like google search while typing a character in editfield - blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I have one array like below

```
String[] currencyList={RUB,AFN,EUR,ALL,GBP,GGP,DZD,EUR,AOA,XCD,XCD,ARS,AMD,AWG,SHP,AUD,EUR};
```

If I entered `A` in the editfield, I want to display words starting with A letters only, like google search.

How do I do this in BlackBerry Java?

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the BlackBerry [AutoCompleteField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/AutoCompleteField.html).

You can find an example [online here](http://developer.blackberry.com/java/documentation/ui_autocomplete_fields_1988860_11.html).

In your case, you would probably use something like this:

```
BasicFilteredList filterList = new BasicFilteredList();
String[] currencyList = {RUB,AFN,EUR,ALL,GBP,GGP,DZD,EUR,AOA,XCD,XCD,ARS,AMD,AWG,SHP,AUD,EUR};   
int uniqueID = 0;
filterList.addDataSet(uniqueID,currencyList,"currency",BasicFilteredList.COMPARISON_IGNORE_CASE);
AutoCompleteField autoCompleteField = new AutoCompleteField(filterList);
add(autoCompleteField);
```